# childNodes not appending to a parent node

Tags: javascript, dom

I am really trying to gain a good grasp of the DOM especially traversing the DOM.  I have a simple html table with form to help with this understanding.  The id of my table is "myTbl" and the id of an empty div is "myDiv".  I want to render the children of "myTbl" into "myDiv" but it isn't working as I would expect. I get the error "**Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null**' It's been very frustrating.  Please help.  Thanks!

```js
var myTbl = document.getElementById("myTbl");
var myDiv = document.querySelector("myDiv");

myDiv.appendChild(myTbl.childNodes);
```

```html
<table border=1 id="myTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>Name of Requestor&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text"></td>
    <td>Request Date<input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Installation Assigned<input type="radio" id="loc1"><input type="radio" id="loc2"></td>
    <td>State/Country<input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employer<input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/isogunro/fzLy42ns/5/

Answer (score 0):

Your selector for `myDiv` is wrong, it has to select an ID, so either use `.getElementById("myDiv")` or `.querySelector("#myDiv")`.

And the other problem is, that you need to append each element individually.

```js
var myTbl = document.getElementById("myTbl");
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

var childs = Array.from(myTbl.childNodes);
childs.forEach(c => myDiv.appendChild(c));
```

```html
<table border=1 id="myTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>Name of Requestor&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text"></td>
    <td>Request Date<input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Installation Assigned<input type="radio" id="loc1"><input type="radio" id="loc2"></td>
    <td>State/Country<input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employer<input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```